# Проблема с ufw/dante/telegram

Tags: ubuntu, telegram, ufw

Добрый вечер. В связи с последними событиями решил сделать прокси сервер для телеграма. На ubuntu 16.04 стоит dante на порте 1080. Ufw этот порт разрешает. При подключении прокси в телеграмме сообщения работают нормально, но при попытке звонка зависает на стадии "соединение". Когда отключаю ufw (ну или ставлю весь входящий трафик на allow), все работает прекрасно. В чем может быть дело?

ufw

```
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----                
1080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

File: /etc/danted.conf

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
logoutput: stderr

internal: venet0:0 port = 1080
external: venet0:0

method: username

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}

pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

Comment: По пробуйте в настройках клиента убрать галочку использовать для звонков....

Comment: Тогда пропадает возможность звонить через прокси :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 1080
```

Должно работать.